# How to compare a set of values in visual basic

Tags: vba

```
  If Target.Column = 6 Then
  End If
```

I would like the If code to be execute if the Column is 6 or 8 or 10. How should I modify the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more specifically what you asked:

```
If Target.Column = 6 OR Target.Column = 8 OR Target.Column = 10 Then
'Code for if a match is found.
else
'Code for when a match isn't found.
End If
```

Or as astander displayed:

```
Select Case Target.Column
Case 6, 8, 10
'Code for if a match is found.
Case Else
'Code for when a match isn't found.
End Select
```

Or even another way:

```
With Target
If .Column = 6 Or .Column = 8 OR .Column = 10 then
'Code for if a match is found.
else
'Code for when a match isn't found.
End If
End with
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case statement

[CASE Statement (VBA)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php)

See the section

```
You can also comma delimit values. For example:


Select Case LNumber
    Case 1, 2
       LRegionName = "North"
    Case 3, 4, 5
       LRegionName = "South"
    Case 6
       LRegionName = "East"
    Case 7, 11
       LRegionName = "West"
 End Select
```